# Does slice and shift do 0 based counting on the array?

Tags: ruby

In this example below:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
a.slice(1,3)
```

in the `slice` method, we are saying to start at position `1` (which is `2`), then continue for 3 elements. When we continue for 3 elements, are we counting the start position or not?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, apparently, according to the CLI

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5] => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 
a.slice(1,3)    => [2, 3, 4]
```

You should install the CLI to play around, its great to try things like this out

Comment: I did try it in the CLI. Except I was interpreting as in it starts at position 1 which is 2 and counts (length - 1) where in this case it (3-1) or 2 ahead. So I wanted to see which one was correct.

Comment: Oh, welp, `a.slice(1,1)` wouldnt work if that was the case but yields `[2]` so I guess its confirmed

Comment: Why would anybody guess if there is a detailed documentation [`Array#slice`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-slice)?

Comment: But no where did it say if the length parameter should start counting at the start index or after the start index.